# Change Windows user password remotely using .NET

Tags: .net, active-directory

How do I change a local user account password remotely using VB.NET/C#?

I have looked into the DirectoryEntry class and know how to add users to a group but cannot figure out how to change a (local) password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using .net 3.5:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "user");
```

The user can change her own password:

```
user.ChangePassword("old", "new");
```

Or, if you run as AD administrator, you can reset it:

```
user.SetPassword("1234567");
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to change passwords for non-domain users on a remote machine.

Comment: In that case, I believe `ContextType.Machine` should work. Not quite sure, never dealt with local users. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way to modify local (i.e. non-domain) users. I'll try ContextType.Machine, but how will I tell it which machine to use?

Comment: Ta, this worked. Turns out UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, strMyServerName) with context being a ContextType.Machine worked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

This might work with .net 3.5 and higher but it requires the server service (i.e. file sharing) be enabled and running. What if it is not???

I would simply prefer the good old, lovely, prefect and guaranteed ADSI syntax right from the heart of a VB.Net assembly (which works like a charm BTW)...Example:

```
Dim uName as string = "trgtUser"
Dim uPass as string = "newPass"
Dim user = GetObject("WinNT://./" & uName & ",user")
user.SetPassword(uPass)
```

That is all there is to set passwords on local machine!!

have fun ;)

Comment: and it does not require System.DirectoryServices.